# Can't install using pip inside a virtual environment because it is looking somewhere else

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

The location of my virtual environments is `/home/tabakade/PycharmProjects/environments/myvenv`
where `tabakade` is my username.
When I try installing package using `pip`, it looks somewhere else and this shows up.

```
(myvenv) tabakade@tabakade-ideapad:~/PycharmProjects/environments$ pip install selenium
/home/tabakade/PycharmProjects/environments/myvenv/bin/python3: error: Found argument '/home/tabakade/PycharmProjects/environments/myvenv/bin/pip' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
python3 [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```

Why is it looking in the wrong directory and how do I fix it?
I have gone through several issues related but couldn't find my solution. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Not a dull answer, but try: 'python -m pip install...'

Comment: I get an error: `python: error: Found argument '-m' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`

Comment: where are you typing these commands? are you on a terminal shell? The usage output does not seem familiar
```
~/
❯ which python
/Users/gui_talarico/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python

~/
❯ python -m pip --version
pip 19.2.1 from /Users/gui_talarico/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```